# I want to deploy an image Docker ( perhaps to tomcat ? or other)

Tags: docker, jenkins, deployment

I want to deploy an image docker which is in my private docker registry, I don't know how to deploy it and on which server ( tomcat, Kubernetes? or ....).
I want to do it with a job or pipeline Jenkins in the same machine. Thank you for your proposals

Comment: At a high-level, you would create a dockerfile which uses a tomcat/nginx image to host the application (JAR/WAR), install docker on your server, then have your Jenkins pipeline run the same docker run my-image command with the appropriate port mappings to expose the image externally.

Comment: Definitely recommend checking out a few tutorials before escalating to StackOverflow - people definitely appreciate questions about specific issues instead of "How do I do this thing I haven't tried?".
https://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/deploying-your-first-web-app-to-tomcat-on-docker

Comment: Last I checked, Tomcat does not run Docker containers

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to address this, a sample action would be something like this

- Have a Dockerfile with required statements as per your requirement within your codebase or context path
- Create a jenkins pipeline with docker plugin(you may have to set the credentials of your private registry in plugins section)
- Let it build and push based on hook or manual action.

Makesure you tag your images well and keep them unique.